# Concurrency in Android

Tags: java, android, database, concurrency

I have case like 2 sales ID are going to order item AT THE SAME TIME with different amount. The DB (any DB) should be automatically do mathematics to the quantity of the item. Let say my current stock for itemA is 100, and sales1 order 50 and sales2 order 20 AT THE SAME TIME. How do I solve this? Should I handle the concurrency in Android Studio or the DB will automatically handle this kind of transactions ?

Comment: From two different devices?  There's no way for the client to handle it.  That's server side functionality.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I handle the concurrency in Android Studio or the DB will automatically handle this kind of transactions ?

Server have to handle this for you

When Sale1 orders itemA through your app, your app will open a connection to server and do some business. There is a Session created for Sale1's app

The same thing happens to Sale2's app so there are 2 different Sessions

Comment: how about current quantity is 50 and sale1 order 30 of itemA and sale2 order 30 of itemA? Either one should be given message that the availabiltiy quantity is not enough. Anything will happen in this kind situation ?